# when i run sudo bundle install i get this error any help for that?

Tags: linux

```
─$ sudo bundle install
```

Command output:

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/......
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using minitest 5.15.0
Installing ansi 1.5.0
Using ast 2.4.2
Using fiber-local 1.0.0
Using nio4r 2.5.8
Using timers 4.3.3
Installing buftok 0.2.0
Using bundler 2.2.32
Using daemons 1.4.1
Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.7
Using eventmachine 1.2.7
Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Installing equalizer 0.0.11
Installing erubis 2.7.0
Using espeak-ruby 1.0.5
Installing execjs 2.8.1
Using ffi 1.15.4
Using hashie 5.0.0
Using http-form_data 2.3.0
Using http-accept 1.7.0
Using json 2.6.1
Installing maxmind-db 1.1.1
Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
Using mime-types-data 3.2021.1115
Using mojo_magick 0.6.6
Using msgpack 1.4.2
Using multipart-post 2.1.1
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.5
Installing naught 1.1.0
Installing netrc 0.11.0
Using parallel 1.21.0
Using parseconfig 1.1.2
Using rqrcode_core 0.2.0
Using rack 2.2.3
Using rainbow 3.1.1
Using regexp_parser 2.2.1
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using ruby-progressbar 1.11.0
Using unicode-display_width 2.1.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Installing simple_oauth 0.3.1
Installing tilt 2.0.10
Using slack-notifier 2.4.0
Installing sqlite3 1.4.2
Using sync 0.5.0
Using webrick 1.7.0
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Using i18n 1.10.0
Using console 1.13.1
Using ffi-compiler 1.0.1
Installing hashie-forbidden_attributes 0.1.1
Using mime-types 3.4.1
Using mustermann 1.1.1
Using parser 3.1.1.0
Using qr4r 0.6.1
Using rack-protection 2.2.0
Using tins 1.29.1
Using msfrpc-client 1.1.2
Using thin 1.8.1
Using xmlrpc 0.3.2
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using activesupport 7.0.2.2
Using http-parser 1.2.3
Using async 1.30.1
Using term-ansicolor 1.7.1
Using activemodel 7.0.2.2
Using rubocop-ast 1.16.0
Using async-io 1.32.2
Using activerecord 7.0.2.2
Using async-dns 1.3.0
Using rubocop 1.26.0
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find ansi-1.5.0.gem for installation
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:177:in `install'                                                                                                                                                                               /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing ansi (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
ansi

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find buftok-0.2.0.gem for installation
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:177:in `install'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing buftok (0.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
twitter was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
buftok

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find unf_ext-0.0.7.7.gem for installation
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:177:in `install'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
twitter was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
http was resolved to 4.4.1, which depends on
http-cookie was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
domain_name was resolved to 0.5.20190701, which depends on
unf was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
unf_ext

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find http_parser.rb-0.6.0.gem for installation
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:177:in `install'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing http_parser.rb (0.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.3, which depends on
http_parser.rb

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find equalizer-0.0.11.gem for installation
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:177:in `install'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing equalizer (0.0.11), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
twitter was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
equalizer

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find erubis-2.7.0.gem for installation
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:177:in `install'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing erubis (2.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
erubis

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find execjs-2.8.1.gem for installation
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:177:in `install'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'   /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing execjs (2.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

..................................................................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

just run it without sudo command, when you use sudo means you're running it as root.